# jquery onclick add margin-left

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, onclick

I'm trying something pretty simple in JS but I can't make it work...

I would like when clicking on a `div` to add a negative `margin-left` to another `div`, but I want it to happen every time I click on the `div`, not just once as it does now.
Every time I click on my `#next_nav`, I would like the `#nav` to move from `-10px`.
Here it only works one time.
Here is my JS:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#next_nav').click(function() {
    $("#nav").css('margin-left', '-10px');
  });
});
```

and my HTML:

```html
<div id="next_nav"></div>
<div id="nav"></div>
```

Here is my JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Beyzd/

Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

add an `=` in front of your value:

```
$(function() {
    $('#next_nav').click(function() {
       $('#nav').css('margin-left', '-=10px');
    });
});
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Beyzd/6/)**

**EDIT**

If you want to animate it, use `animate()` method. Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Beyzd/10/) for you.

Comment: is it possible to add animation to make it move ? like .animate slow ?

Comment: thanks @AloneInTheDark, but in your fiddle the margin is not 10px, and when clicking again on the #next_nav, my nav takes its initial position, do you know why ?

Comment: Because there is a "toggle" value in the function. Toggle means, a property can be on/off with an action event. You can change this value (i don't remember how to disable right now).
I guess there is no parameter like "margin" in animate() function. You can read some documents about it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
var pixels=0;
$(function() {
    $('#next_nav').click(function () {
       pixels=pixels-10;      
       $( "#nav" ).css('margin-left',pixels);
    });
});
```

[Working fiddle is available here.](http://jsfiddle.net/Beyzd/5/)

Answer (score 1):

Check on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Beyzd/9/)

```
   $(document).ready(function (){
       $("#next_nav").on("click", function() {
          var $left = $("#nav").css('margin-left');
          var $newval = (parseInt($left) - 10) + "px";
          $("#nav").css ({
            'margin-left' : $newval
          });
       });
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
  var count=0;
  $('#next_nav').click(function () {
  count-=10;

$( "#nav" ).css('margin-left',count);
});
});
```

And include jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it for you:
[Updated version](http://jsfiddle.net/Beyzd/3/)

edit the `.css('margin-left','-10px');` to `.css({'margin-left' : '-10px'});`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function() {
$('#next_nav').click(function () {
  marginleft=parseInt($( "#nav" ).css('margin-left').replace('px',''));
  $( "#nav" ).css('margin-left',marginleft-10+'px');
});
});
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Beyzd/4/)**

Answer (score 0):

just change  this `$( "#nav" ).css('margin-left','-=10px');`