# Javascript function works on JSFiddle but not in my HTML document?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, function

So, I found a code/function I wanted to use on this site here: [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22146904/jquery-onclick-add-margin-left)

I then copied the code from the second answer, did some small changes and tested if it actually worked, and I found out it did not. All of the functions from the link work on JSFiddle tho, but none of them work for me in my html document.

I did < script>, didn't work. I tried to make a separate .js document, but the code was still not working.

```
<body>

<div id="bokse2"></div>
<div id="boksi"></div>

<script src="test.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>

$(function() {
$('#bokse2').click(function() {
    $('#boksi').css('margin-left', '-=10px');
});
});

</script>
</body>
```

The big box (boksi) should move 10 pixels to the left by clicking on the smaller box (bokse2). Just like it does here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q1pfouj2/)

Comment: Looks like you need to include the jQuery library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the include to the jQuery

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
```